# How does android implement run-as without setuid

Tags: permissions, users, android, setuid

Earlier versions of Android have at `run-as` executable with the `setuid` flag set so it runs as `root`, but more recent versions do away with that. What changed? How can the `shell` user effect a user change?

I've taken a quick look at the [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core.git/+/android-8.0.0_r34/run-as/run-as.cpp) but my linux coding skills are pretty weak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which changed was that runas instead of switching to root user it runs with the SETUID and SETGID [capabilities](https://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities) which are based on the executable files extended attributes. Those can be set with the setcap command.