# How does Magisk on Android work as su without setuid and capabilities?

Tags: root, android, su, setuid, capabilities

I've read in [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/406170/27672) that on Android the `su` binaries avoid needing to be `setuid` by using filesystem capabilities like `cap_setuid`. But then I tried to check this, and to my surprise, I found no capabilities set on my Magisk-enabled Android 8.0 system.

Here's how I checked:

1. Logged in via SimpleSSHD
2. `scp`'ed the following binaries taken from Debian arm64 packages `libcap2`, `libcap2-bin` and `libc6`:

   - `getcap`
   - `libc.so.6`
   - `libcap.so.2.25`
   - `libcap.so.2`
   - `ld-2.27.so`
3. Had the following terminal session on the phone:

```
$ su
# whoami
root
# exit

$ type su
su is /sbin/su

$ ls -lh /sbin/su
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 2018-08-12 22:40 /sbin/su -> /sbin/magisk

$ ls -lh /sbin/magisk
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 94 2018-08-12 22:40 /sbin/magisk

$ sed 's@^@> @' /sbin/magisk
> #!/system/bin/sh
> unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
> unset LD_PRELOAD
> exec /sbin/magisk.bin "${0##*/}" "$@"

$ ls -lh /sbin/magisk.bin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 71K 2018-08-12 22:40 /sbin/magisk.bin

$ file /sbin/magisk.bin
/sbin/magisk.bin: ELF shared object, 32-bit LSB arm, dynamic (/system/bin/linker), stripped

$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./ld-2.27.so ./getcap -v /sbin/magisk.bin
/sbin/magisk.bin
```

As you can see, neither `setuid` bit, nor any capabilities are present in the `/sbin/magisk.bin` binary. So what's going on? How does it work?

Comment: [How does Magisk work?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213344/218526)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that `/sbin/magisk.bin` the non-root user launches doesn't spawn the root shell by itself. Instead, it communicates its request to `magiskd`, which is executed as root. And `magiskd`, after checking for permissions, executes the command requested. (Interestingly, `magiskd` is the same binary – `/sbin/magisk.bin`, but run by `init` as root).

You can check this as follows:

```
$ echo $$
27699

$ su

# echo $PPID
2606

# exit

$ su

# echo $PPID
2606

# ps -A|egrep '^[^ ]+ +2606'
root          2606     1   16044   2068 __skb_recv_datagram eb4d2fe0 S magiskd
```

Note that in the output above, after we `exit` the superuser shell and re-enter it, parent PID still remains the same (2606 in this session), but not equal to the PID of the original non-root shell (27699 in this session). Moreover, parent PID of `magiskd` is 1, i.e. `init`, which is one more confirmation that it's not what we started from our non-root shell.

Comment: It looks like `/sbin/magisk.bin` is  designed like Busybox... essentially, an executable library of commands (at least 2 in this case). The code chooses which to execute based on the symlink it was invoked through. That can be done with `bash` scripts too.